# Couchbase to local files export

Tags: couchbase, sqoop2, sqoop

I need to migrate the couchbase data into HDFS but the db and Hadoop clusters are not accessible to each other. So I cannot use sqoop in the recommended way.  Is there a way to import couchbase data into local files (instead of HDFS) using sqoop. If it is possible I can do that and then transfer the local files using ftp and then use sqoop again to transfer them to HDFS.

If that's a bad solution, then is there any other way I can transfer all the cb data in local files.  Creating views on this cb cluster is a difficult task and I would like to avoid using it.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative solution (perhaps not as elegant, but it works):

1. Use Couchbase backup utility: cbbackup and save locally all data.
2. Transfer backup files to HDFS reachable network host.
3. Install Couchbase in the network segment where HDFS is reachable and use Couchbase restore from backup procedure to populate that instance.
4. Use Scoop (in recommended way) against that Couchbase instance that has access to HDFS.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the cbbackup utility that comes with the Couchbase installation to export all data to backup files. By default the backups are actually stored in SQLite format, so you can move them to your Hadoop cluster and then use any JDBC SQLite driver to import the data from each *.cbb file individually with Sqoop. I actually wrote a [blog](http://codehardblog.azurewebsites.net/exporting-data-from-couchbase-server/) about this a while ago, you can check it out.

To get you started, here's one of the many [JDBC SQLite drivers](https://bitbucket.org/xerial/sqlite-jdbc) out there.

Comment: This seems like a very possible solution :)  Thanks for suggesting.  One question  ;   How does cbbackup take care of replicas ?  in other words, if we take cbbackup from all the nodes , will it contain multiple copies of the same data or it figures out internally ?

Comment: No, cbbackup only exports active data and ignores replicas.

Answer (score 0):

You can use couchbase kafka adapter to stream data from couchbase to kafka and from kafka you can store in any file system you like. CouchbaseKafka adapter uses TAP protocol to push data to kafka.

https://github.com/paypal/couchbasekafka